Heapmap via coordinates: Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`
I am trying to create heatmaps based on coordinates.  My data look like this:
data<-structure(list(Date.Time = c("2024-04-06 10:35:30", "2024-04-06 10:40:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:45:30", "2024-04-06 10:50:30", "2024-04-06 10:35:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:40:30", "2024-04-06 10:45:30", "2024-04-06 10:50:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:35:30", "2024-04-06 10:40:30", "2024-04-06 10:45:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:50:30", "2024-04-06 10:35:30", "2024-04-06 10:40:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:45:30", "2024-04-06 10:50:30", "2024-04-06 10:35:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:40:30", "2024-04-06 10:45:30", "2024-04-06 10:50:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:35:30", "2024-04-06 10:40:30", "2024-04-06 10:45:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:50:30", "2024-04-06 10:35:30", "2024-04-06 10:40:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:45:30", "2024-04-06 10:50:30", "2024-04-06 10:35:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:40:30", "2024-04-06 10:45:30", "2024-04-06 10:50:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:35:30", "2024-04-06 10:40:30", "2024-04-06 10:45:30", 
                               "2024-04-06 10:50:30"), Index = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 103L, 
                                                                 103L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
                                                                 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 
                                                                 109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L), Test1 = c(478L, 
                                                                                                                                  888L, 552L, 502L, 626L, 913L, 727L, 636L, 637L, 11928L, 836L, 
                                                                                                                                  615L, 740L, 1209L, 941L, 660L, 973L, 1266L, 700L, 840L, 441L, 
                                                                                                                                  8028L, 616L, 659L, 538L, 8639L, 612L, 496L, 812L, 999L, 768L, 
                                                                                                                                  542L, 460L, 1488L, 597L, 691L), Test2 = c(1L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 112L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            4L, 2029L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 48L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            0L), Test3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 95L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Long = c(-14449.287, -14449.287, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -14449.287, -14449.287, -14449.278, -14449.278, -14449.278, -14449.278, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -14449.257, -14449.257, -14449.257, -14449.257, -14449.29, -14449.29, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -14449.29, -14449.29, -14449.287, -14449.287, -14449.287, -14449.287, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -14449.246, -14449.246, -14449.246, -14449.246, -14449.273, -14449.273, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -14449.273, -14449.273, -14449.27, -14449.27, -14449.27, -14449.27, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -14449.27, -14449.27, -14449.27, -14449.27), Lat = c(4537.509, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              4537.509, 4537.509, 4537.509, 4537.51, 4537.51, 4537.51, 4537.51, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              4537.485, 4537.485, 4537.485, 4537.485, 4537.516, 4537.516, 4537.516, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              4537.516, 4537.505, 4537.505, 4537.505, 4537.505, 4537.478, 4537.478, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              4537.478, 4537.478, 4537.499, 4537.499, 4537.499, 4537.499, 4537.497, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              4537.497, 4537.497, 4537.497, 4537.506, 4537.506, 4537.506, 4537.506
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))

Following the suggestion written here, I reorganized my data and attempted to generate the plots.
df1<-data.frame(long = rep(data$Long, data$Test1),
                lat = rep(data$Lat, data$Test1),
                time = rep(data$Date.Time, data$Test1),
                index = rep(data$Index, data$Test1))
df2<-data.frame(long = rep(data$Long, data$Test2),
                lat = rep(data$Lat, data$Test2),
                time = rep(data$Date.Time, data$Test2),
                index = rep(data$Index, data$Test2))
df3<-data.frame(long = rep(data$Long, data$Test3),
                lat = rep(data$Lat, data$Test3),
                time = rep(data$Date.Time, data$Test3),
                index = rep(data$Index, data$Test3))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
  lims(x=c(-14449.4, -14449.1), y=c(4537.4, 4537.65))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-14449.3, -14449.23), ylim=c(4537.45, 4537.53)) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level.., alpha=..level..),
                 geom="polygon") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=rev(brewer.pal(7, "Spectral"))) +
  facet_wrap(~time, nrow=2)

Test2 (df2) at the 10:40:30 timestamp isn't populating and results in the error message:
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`
Caused by error in `MASS::kde2d()`:
! bandwidths must be strictly positive


1.) I read here that this is due to stat_density2d() using MASS::kde2d, which uses MASS::bandwidth.nrd(df2$long) to calculate the bandwidth.  It subtracts the 3rd quantile (75%) from the first quantile (25%).  And this difference needs to be greater than 0.  Using MASS::bandwidth.nrd(df2$long) and quantile(df2$long), my quantiles looks like this:
bandwidth.nrd(df2$long)    
[1] 0

quantile(df2$long)
           0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
    -14449.29 -14449.25 -14449.25 -14449.25 -14449.25 

Is there anything I can do to get around this problem?
2.) Why is the red in the legend labeled as 1600 when the highest value on the 10:45:30 graph is 5?
Thanks for any insight!
